# NoReverseMatch at /cart/ 'car' is not a registered namespace Error in Python Django

Tags: python, django

I ran my Django project and I got this error when I went to /cart/.

NoReverseMatch at /cart/
'car' is not a registered namespace

I checked all of my code but never written 'car'.

This is my urls.py of project.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from shop import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('search/', include('search_app.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    path('order/', include('order.urls')),
    path('account/create/', views.signupView, name='signup'),
    path('account/login/', views.signinView, name='signin'),
    path('account/logout/', views.signoutView, name='signout'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += 
static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += 
static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my urls.py of cart app.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:sitting_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('remove/<int:sitting_id>/', views.cart_remove, 
name='cart_remove'),
    path('full_remove/<int:sitting_id>/', views.full_remove, 
name='full_remove'),               
]
```

This is my models.py of cart app.

```
from django.db import models 
from shop.models import Sitting

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id

class CartItem(models.Model):
    sitting = models.ForeignKey(Sitting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CartItem'

    def sub_total(self):
            return self.sitting.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sitting
```

This is my views.py of cart app.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from shop.models import Sitting
from .models import Cart, CartItem
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from order.models import Order, OrderItem
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart

def add_cart(request, sitting_id):
    sitting = Sitting.objects.get(id=sitting_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
                cart_id = _cart_id(request)    
            )
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(sitting=sitting, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.sitting.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
                    sitting = sitting,
                    quantity = 1,
                    cart = cart
             )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items = None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.sitting.price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    stripe_total = int(total * 100)
    description = 'Travel Sitter - Reserve'
    data_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #  print(request.POST)
       try:
          token = request.POST['stripeToken']
          email = request.POST['stripeEmail']
          billingName = request.POST['stripeBillingName']
          billingAddress1 = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressLine1']
          billingcity = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressCity']
          billingPostcode = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressZip']
          billingCountry = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressCountryCode']
          shippingName = request.POST['stripeShippingName']
          shippingAddress1 = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressLine1']
          shippingcity = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressCity']
          shippingPostcode = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressZip']
          shippingCountry = 
    request.POST['stripeShippingAddressCountryCode']
          customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                      email=email,
                      source = token
              )
          charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                      amount=stripe_total,
                      currency="usd",
                      description=description,
                      customer=customer.id
              )
          try:
              order_details = Order.objects.create(
                      token = token,
                      total = total,
                      emailAddress = email,
                      billingName = billingName,
                      billingAddress1 = billingAddress1,
                      billingCity = billingcity,
                      billingPostcode = billingPostcode,
                      billingCountry = billingCountry,
                      shippingName = shippingName,
                      shippingAddress1 = shippingAddress1,
                      shippingCity = shippingcity,
                      shippingPostcode = shippingPostcode,
                      shippingCountry = shippingCountry
                  )
              order_details.save()
              for order_item in cart_items:
                 oi = OrderItem.objects.create(
                         sitting = order_item.sitting.name,
                         quantity = order_item.quantity,
                         price = order_item.sitting.price,
                         order = order_details 
                     )
                 oi.save()

                 sittings = Sitting.objects.get(id=order_item.sitting.id)
                 sittings.stock = int(order_item.sitting.stock - 
 order_item.quantity)
                 sittings.save()
                 order_item.delete()

                 print('The Reservation has been created')
              try:
                 sendEmail(order_details.id)
                 print('The order email has been sent to the customer.')
              except IOError as e:
                  return e
              return redirect('order:thanks', order_details.id)
          except ObjectDoesNotExist:
               pass
       except stripe.error.CardError as e:
           return False,e
    return render(request, 'cart.html', dict(cart_items = cart_items, total = total, counter = counter, data_key = data_key, stripe_total = stripe_total, description = description))



def cart_remove(request, sitting_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    sitting = get_object_or_404(Sitting, id=sitting_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(sitting=sitting, cart=cart)
    if cart_item.quantity > 1:
        cart_item.quantity -= 1
        cart_item.save()
    else:
        cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')  

def full_remove(request, sitting_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    sitting = get_object_or_404(Sitting, id=sitting_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(sitting=sitting, cart=cart)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def sendEmail(order_id):
    transaction = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=transaction)
    try:
        subject = "Sitter - Reservation #{}".format(transaction.id)
        to = ['{}'.format(transaction.emailAddress)]
        from_email = "orders@sitter.com"
        order_information = {
        'transaction' : transaction,
        'order_items' : order_items                       
        }
        message = get_template('email/email.html').render(order_information)
        msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=to, from_email=from_email)
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.send()
    except IOError as e:
        return e
```

This is my templates of cart.(cart.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block metadescription %}
    This is your reservation page. Proceed to reserve.
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    Cart - Sitter
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if not cart_items %}
        <div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <br>
                <h1 class="text-center my_title">
                    You have not had any reservations.
                </h1>
                <br>
                <p class="text-center">
                    Please click <a href="[% url 'shop:allProdCat' 
%}">here</a> to continue reserving. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <br>
                <h1 class="test-center my_title">
                    Your reservation
                </h1>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mx-auto">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
                <table class="table my_custom_table">
                    <thead class="my_custom_thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th clospan="5">
                                Your Reservation
                            </th>
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for cart_item in cart_items %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{cart_item.sitting.get_url}}"><img src="{{cart_item.sitting.image.url}}" alt="" class="float-left rounded custom_image"></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    {{cart_item.sitting.name}}
                                    <br>
                                    SKU: {{cart_item.sitting.id}}
                                    <br>
                                    Unit Price: ${{cart_item.sitting.price}}
                                    <br>
                                    Qty: {{cart_item.quantity}} ×　${{cart_item.sitting.price}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    ${{cart_item.sub_total}}
                                </td>
                                {% if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.sitting.stock %}
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{% url 'cart:add_cart' cart_item.sitting.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle custom_icon"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' cart_item.sitting.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle custom_icon"></i></a><a href="{% url 'car:add_cart' cart_item.sitting.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle custom_icon"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                {% else %}
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;<a href="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' cart_item.sitting.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle custom_icon"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'cart:full_remove' cart_item.sitting.id %}" class="custom_icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
                <table class="table my_custom_table">
                    <thead class="my_custom_thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Checkout
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Please review your reservation before proceeding with the order payment.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                Your total is: <strong>${{ total }}</strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="mx-auto">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <script
                        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                        data-key="{{ data_key }}"
                        data-image="{% static 'img/atom.png' %}"
                        data-name="Travel Sitter"
                        data-description="{{ description }}"
                        data-amount="{{ stripe_total }}"
                        data-locale="auto"
                        data-currency="usd"
                        data-shipping-address="true"
                        data-billing-address="true"
                        data-zip-code="true">
                      </script>

                    </form>
                    <a href="{% url 'shop:allProdCat' %}" class="vtn btn-secondary btn-block my_custom_button">Make the other reservation</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

If I have to show the other code, please teach me.
I am new to Python. I trace a lecture and changed somethings.
Please teach me.
Thank you.

Comment: You made a typo: replace `{% url 'car:add_cart' cart_item.sitting.id %}` to `{% url 'cart:add_cart' cart_item.sitting.id %}`.

Comment: Please do not just following a lecture to change something. Usually it is better to try to understand what is going on and what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

your namespace `app_name` and `app name` is same
so use different